# Postgresql - query to get difference in data count

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, today's_table and yeterday's_table.
I need to compare the data for an interval of 15 mins at exact same times for today and yesterday.

For example, for below data let's I need to check from 00:00:00 and 00:15:00 on 20201202 and 20201202. So difference should come out as '3' since the yesterday's_table has 8 records and today's_table has 5 records.

today's_table:

[image: Date]

Yesterday's table:

[image]

I tried something like; (consider now() is 00:15:00)

```
select count(*) from yeterday's_table where time between now() - interval "24 hours" and now() - interval "23 hours 45 mins"
minus
select count(*) from today's_table where time = now() - interval "15 minutes";
```

is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with subqueries:

```
SELECT b.c - a.c
  FROM (select count(*) as c from yeterdays_table where time between now() - interval '24 hours' and now() - interval '23 hours 45 mins') a, 
(select count(*) as c from todays_table where time = now() - interval '15 minutes') b;
```

Bear in mind you need to single-quote your intervals, and your table names cannot have quotes in them.

Comment: Thanks @richyen , can I extend this query across two DB's??

Comment: no you cannot.  That's a limitation in Postgres.  There are ways around it, namely through using Foreign Data Wrappers (FDWs).  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html